# Node - Bluemix Object Storage

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I wanted to try Object Storage with my Bluemix account.

The frontend is sending me image in base64 encoding.

I wanted to know how I can store a file (by writing a new temporary one), and upload it on Object Storage?

I successfully uploaded a file by giving path in a parameter, but here I only have base64 data.

Does someone have a point to start?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the Object Storage Node SDK:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-serversdk-nodejs

Or you could use [pkgcloud](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud) too:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016 IBM Corp.
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */


(function (module) {
    var pkgcloud = require('pkgcloud'),
        fs = require('fs');

    function ObjectStorage(container, credentials) {
        this.container = container;

        this.config = {
            provider: 'openstack',
            useServiceCatalog: true,
            useInternal: false,
            keystoneAuthVersion: 'v3',
            authUrl: credentials.auth_url,
            tenantId: credentials.projectId,
            domainId: credentials.domainId,
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password,
            region: credentials.region
        };

        this.client = pkgcloud.storage.createClient(this.config);
    }

    ObjectStorage.prototype.validate = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            this.client.auth(function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }

                resolve();
            });
        }.bind(this));
    };

    ObjectStorage.prototype.makeContainer = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            this.client.createContainer({name: this.container}, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }

                return resolve();
            });

        }.bind(this));
    };

    ObjectStorage.prototype.uploadFile = function (path, name) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            var myPicture = fs.createReadStream(path);

            var upload = this.client.upload({
                container: this.container,
                remote: name
            });

            upload.on('error', function (error) {
                reject(error);
            });

            upload.on('success', function (file) {
                resolve(file);
            });

            myPicture.pipe(upload);
        }.bind(this));
    };

    module.exports = ObjectStorage;
})(module);
```

Comment: Thank you guy, i'll make a try on this package

Comment: The "Object Storage Node SDK" package works really well. Thx.